# I upgraded my machine type and now my program doesn't connect to the Internet

Tags: virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

I'm a total newbie freaking out.

I'm running Followliker (an instagram automation tool) in a Google Cloud powered virtual machine. 
About an hour ago, I decided to upgrade from a "1 vCPU, 3.3 GB" to a "2 vCPU 5,5 GB" Machine Type without really knowing what I was doing.

Since the switch, the program doesn't connect to the internet!
The virtual machine is indeed online but something prevents Followliker from going online.

What can I do?! Any kind of help will be much appreciated!
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does the vMachine still have internet and did you make any changes to the virtual network?

Comment: Yes, the Virtual Machine does have internet. I don't think I change anything in the virtual network. No that I know. I only clicked upgrade. the VM restarted and that was it. The new (upgraded VM) loaded.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the program?  If the machine can hit instagram and or instagrams API, it is just the program and it has possibly become corrupt during the upgrade.

Comment: maybe Followliker generates some authentication code based on hardware configuration.

Comment: Could well be. I'll back up the many gathered GB of data and will reinstall and comment. Thanks a lot for your support!